# Finding image url via using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, find, match

Any working Regex to find image url ?

Example :

```
var reg = /^url\(|url\(".*"\)|\)$/;

var string = 'url("http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg")';

var string2 = 'url(http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg)';


console.log(string.match(reg));
console.log(string2.match(reg));
```

I tied but fail with this `reg`
pattern will look like this, I just want image url between `url(" ")` or `url( )`

I just want to get output like `http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg`

http://jsbin.com/ahewaq/1/edit

Comment: Are you just trying to extract the URL from the string?

Comment: I just want to get output like `http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg` @JamesHill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply use this expression:

```
/url.*\("?([^")]+)/
```

This returns an array, where the first index (0) contains the entire match, the second will be the url itself, like so:

```
'url("http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg")'.match(/url.*\("?([^")]+)/)[1];
//returns "http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg"
//or without the quotes, same return, same expression
'url(http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg)'.match(/url.*\("?([^")]+)/)[1];
```

If there is a change that single and double quotes are used, you can simply replace all `"` by either `'"` or `['"]`, in this case:

```
/url.*\(["']?([^"')]+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp:

```
var regex = /\burl\(\"?(.*?)\"?\)/;
var match = regex.exec(string);
console.log(match[1]);
```

The URL is captured in the first subgroup.

Comment: @l2aelba This is not a helpful comment. What is not working? Did you extract the first subgroup?

Comment: got `["url(http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg)", "http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg"]`in console.log  http://jsbin.com/ahewaq/5/edit

Comment: oh yeahhh !! 2 arrays inside ! sorry

Answer (score -1):

If the string will always be consistent, one option would be simply to remove the first 4 characters `url("` and the last two `")`:

```
var string = 'url("http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg")';

// Remove last two characters
string = string.substr(0, string.length - 2);

// Remove first five characters
string = string.substr(5, string.length);
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvqpG/1/).

**Benefit of this approach:** You can edit it yourself, without asking StackOverflow to do it for you. RegEx is **great**, but if you don't know it, peppering your code with it makes for a frustrating refactor.